# Elasticsearch POST and PUT

Tags: api, elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to elasticsearch and I am trying to learn the APIs.

So usually you use POST to create something new and PUT to update the existing one. But I have noticed that, when I use POST to create new index, I get error saying, use PUT.

And which one do we use for creating new documents PUT or POST. In my case PUT worked, but not POST.
I was looking if I can get a simple explanation to clarify this. I am using Kibana

Answer (score 2):

The [rule of thumb](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index-api-request) is

- Use PUT to create a new document with a specific ID that you provide yourself
- Use POST to create a new document and let Elasticsearch generate a document ID automatically